# HTTP GET Error in a returned promise when creating a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing an extension for Google Chrome, and in a function, I return a promise that uses `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

The method is "POST" and I call an anonymous function with the response I get. Somewhat randomly, I when I say `doc.innerHTML = response`, 
I'll get the 403 GET error in the debugger.

I've tried excluding the URI in my manifest.json, and when I inspect the webpage that is 'forbidden' I get this: "Access denied by load balancer."

My confusion is that I am not actually doing any GET requests, and that the error does not occur every time. Is there a way for me to get around this?

See the code below:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        method: "POST",
        url: //some URL,
        data://some data
      },
      function (response) {
        if (response) {
          const regex = new RegExp(lastName + "\\W?,\\W?" + firstName, "ig");
          const doc = document.createElement("html");
          doc.innerHTML = response;
          const anchors = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
          Array.from(anchors).forEach(function (anchor) {
            if (anchor.innerHTML.match(regex)) {
              const tid = anchor.getAttribute("href").match(/[0-9]{1,}/g);
              resolve(tid ? tid[0] : null);
            }
          });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps `response` has a img, script, link, iframe etc element that refers to a URL that results in the 403 error

Comment: Realizing that everything after doc.innerHTML=response is unnecessary, sorry about that

Comment: surely you get the URL in the browser console that is causing this error? if not, use a browser with better developer tools :p

Comment: The URL that I am getting is there actually, and its from the website I am running the script on

Comment: so, the URL is in `response` - is that what you're saying? Does this 403 error prevent the rest of your code running?

Comment: The response is from the website I sending the HTTP request to. Unless I am not understanding responses properly?

Comment: The 403 error doesn't prevent the rest of my code from running, but nonetheless, I'd like to know if there is a workaround to avoid it?